how to get the xml subsection in parsimonious?
I have the below grammar and it works fine when the xml elements in the  are in the same line. However, if they are on multiple lines, it does not. I have tried the "sm" regex flag and it still does not work.
How do I get the contents of the <section> ?
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    text = (sections)*
    sections = ws* '<sections>' ws* section_element+ ws* '</sections>' ws*
    section_element = "<section>" section_content "</section>"
    section_content =  ws* value ws* 
    ws = ~"\s*"
    value = ~"[ a-z < > \n\r\s].*"
    """
)

class TextVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    def visit_text(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text

    def visit_section_content(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node


text = """
<sections> 
    <section>
       <abc> aaa </abc> <def>bbb</def>
    </section>
</sections>
"""


tree = grammar.parse(text)
tv = TextVisitor()
extracted_text = tv.visit(tree)
print(extracted_text)


Changing
text = """
<sections> 
    <section>
       <abc> aaa </abc> <def>bbb</def>
    </section>
</sections>
"""

to
text = """
<sections> 
    <section>
       <abc> aaa </abc> 
       <def>bbb</def>
    </section>
</sections>
"""

does not work.

Your value token matches the regular expression .*, so it's going to consume everything, including the closing tags for <section> and <sections>. This will always result in an error.
